# Integral calculation problem

Tags: calculus

[image: Passage]

![[]

Could someone please explain how come the last passage is correct - We don't understand where the 1 went...
Thanks

Comment: Absorbed in the constant. That should better be $C'$ then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is a constant and therefore it is included in C.

Comment: It might be helpful for the OP if you explained this a bit more, perhaps showing, as in showing the last calculation and explaining that the $C$ is a different $C$, not the same one.

Answer (score 0):

In an indefinite integral, we always add the "+C" to the end. This is to account for all possible solutions, because the derivative of an arbitrary constant, is 0. In this example, $t=1-x^4$. When t was substituted back in to the expression we would have:

$-\frac{1}{4}(\ln|1-x^4|-(1-x^4)) + C$.

Notice how the one is a constant as well. Because a constant minus one is still an arbitrary constant, the constant "absorbs" the one; it becomes unnecessary. When you differentiate the above, the derivative of the one will always give you 0, changing nothing.  Some make the argument that we should rewrite $C$ as $C_{1}$ or give it some other notation to denote that after subtracting one, we actually have a "different" constant, but in reality, with or without "absorbing" the one differentiating the above always brings you back to the original expression.